# How to save attachments in Thunderbird on arrival automatically?

Tags: email, thunderbird

How can I save email attachment on its arrival in Thunderbird and save it to specific folder - by some rule of sender or subject of the email automatically?

Comment: This can be done with a Thunderbird extension.  I would check to see if one exists already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Thunderbird extension [AttachmentExtractor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor/). I was looking for something similar and this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to archived thread at Mozilla's Support that may help:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1163703

There's an add-on called FiltaQuilla - https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/ that works with new versions of T.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.